# Relation between solvent accessibility and brownian motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics, brownian-motion

Assume one has a molecule (made of nodes) inside a solvent. If one tries to model the average effect of the interaction between the molecule and the solvent, one has two effects:

1- Friction term on the $i^{th}$ node of the molecule which is something like $-\xi_i v_i$

2- Random force $R_i(t)$ on the $i^{th}$ node resulting from collisions with solvent molecules

If this molecule has a complex shape then generally some residues will be burried and will not be contact on with water. Therefore the solvent accessibility (SA) of different nodes will be different. Yet I have not seen any studies where this is taken into account. If one tries to integrate the Brownian motion equation with a computer wouldn`t it be more correct if

1- One allow random force to be only applied to outer residues and only in the direction from out of the molecule to the inside of the molecule

2- How should the friction coefficient change depending on SA

I once coded a simulation that has taken into account the effect 1. But since my theoretical basis on this topic is not very good I could not really conclude anything. Also the friction coefficient is proportional to collision frequency. So if there is no collision there is no friction? Is is the case the the nodes on the surface of the molecule obey overdamped Langevin equations while those more burried inside just obey newton with usualy forces derived from the potential? References are welcome.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "friction" between nodes of molecules. Can you define this in microscopic terms?

Comment: I never said friction between nodes. The friction is between a node and water molecules. Therefore I guess the coefficient should change depending on whether if the molecule node is surrounded by water molecules or by other molecule nodes.

Comment: I understood what you wrote, but friction between individual molecules is not a well defined physical term. Friction is a mesoscopic phenomenon, not a microscopic one.

Comment: Well as I said I am not very good on the theory. This terms that appears on Langevin equation is called a friction term usually. Sometimes it is also called a drag force and is derived from Stoke`s law. It mimicks the drag force on a spherical object immersed in a solvent.

Comment: Yes, and that's a mesoscopic mechanical force, but that has absolutely nothing to do with solubility, which is a thermodynamic equilibrium phenomenon.

Comment: I also never said solubility? I said solvent accessible area. For instance SA=0 means that the molecule is not in contact with water therefore does not experience any friction. That is what I am asking on how to incorporate into the theory.

Comment: Solvent accessibility would be a matter of how small you make your solid particles and how well you agitate, wouldn't it? You would also need a model for diffusion. Well, actually, if your solid particles are suspended, diffusion of dissolved molecules is probably the major issue. That there is a bit of slow random motion of the solids doesn't sound like of much concern.

Comment: Well I guess I am not able to convey what I am looking for. Imagine a group of hard spherical objects (about the size of a molecule) immersed in water. This group is clustered together (due to internal bonding between spheres) so some of these spheres are on the surface of the cluster, therefore contacting water and some are burried inside not contacting water molecules. Some are subjected to friction and random collisions some are not subjected to both. Would that mean spheres on the outside obey overdamped langevin (assuming high friction) while those inside just newtonian equations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34113/discussion-between-curiousone-and-sina).

Comment: + I think in simulating the behaviour of molecules near (internal) equilibrium, random forces are usually useful for not getting stuck in local minima near the global minima and getting a good sampling of the phase space near the global minima.